# R: Generating indicators that values differ within groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame where each row is an observation and I have two columns:

- the `group` membership of the observation
- the `outcome` for the observation.

I'm trying to create a new variable `outcome_change` that takes a value of 1 if `outcome` is NOT identical for all observations in a given `group` and 0 otherwise.

Shown in the below code (`dat`) is an example of the data I have. Meanwhile, `dat_out1` shows what I'm looking for the code to produce in the presence of no `NA` values. The `dat_out2` is identical except it shows that the same results arise when there are missing values in a group's values.

Surely there is somewhat to do this with dplyr::group_by()? I don't know how to make these comparisons within groups.

```
  # Input (2 groups: 1 with identical values of outcome
  # in the group (group a) and 1 with differing values of
  # outcome in the group (group b) 
  dat <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
                    outcome = c(1,1,1,3,2,2))

  # Output 1: add a variable for all observations belonging to
  # a group where the outcome changed within each group
  dat_out1 <-   data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
                                  outcome = c(1,1,1,3,2,2),
                                  outcome_change = c(0,0,0,1,1,1))

  # Output 2: same as Output 1, but able to ignore NA values
  dat_out2 <-     data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
                              outcome = c(1,1,NA,3,2,NA),
                              outcome_change = c(0,0,0,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Strictly-speaking, you cannot know if outcomes are identical when values are missing.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "observed values" or non missing values are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an aproach:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(outcome_change = ifelse(length(unique(outcome[!is.na(outcome)])) > 1, 1, 0))
#output
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   group outcome outcome_change
  <fctr>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1      a       1              0
2      a       1              0
3      a       1              0
4      b       3              1
5      b       2              1
6      b       2              1
```

with `dat2`

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   group outcome outcome_change
  <fctr>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1      a       1              0
2      a       1              0
3      a      NA              0
4      b       3              1
5      b       2              1
6      b      NA              1
```

Comment: This gets the answer because it is most transparent in what it is doing.

Comment: With even more dplyr, we can simplify the `length(unique(outcome[!is.na(outcome)])) > 1` expression to `n_distinct(outcome, na.rm=TRUE) > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
                  outcome = c(1,1,1,3,2,2))
dat2 <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), 
                   outcome = c(1,1,NA,3,2,NA))

dat_out1 <- dat %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(outcome_change = ifelse(min(outcome) == max(outcome), 0, 1))

dat_out2 <- dat2 %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(outcome_change = ifelse(min(outcome, na.rm = TRUE) == max(outcome, na.rm = TRUE), 0, 1))
```

Comment: Or to be even shorter: `outcome_change = 1 * (min(outcome) == max(outcome))`. Better still, keep it as a logical value, which is natural in the context.

Comment: Good solution. Less transparent than the above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[, outcome_change := as.integer(uniqueN(outcome[!is.na(outcome)])>1), group]
dat1
#   group outcome outcome_change
#1:     a       1              0  
#2:     a       1              0
#3:     a       1              0
#4:     b       3              1
#5:     b       2              1
#6:     b       2              1
```

If we apply the same with 'dat2'

```
dat2
#    group outcome outcome_change2
#1:     a       1               0
#2:     a       1               0
#3:     a      NA               0
#4:     b       3               1
#5:     b       2               1
#6:     b      NA               1
```